# Selecting different colors for touching polygons in random color ramp in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layouts

I am making a map of Africa in QGIS.
The colors selection is randomly, but I need to make sure there are no two similar colors for polygons that are touching each other lake Egypt and Sudan.

[image]

I have tried to change the setting in the color ramp selection, but it did not yield any results. Is there a way to set the setting so there will not be two similar colors one next to each other?

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Qgis/Plugins/Documentation/topocolour/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In qgis 2.99 there is the topological coloring processing tool that give you exactly that (it add a column so after using it you could use your data in earlier version of qgis)

[image]

Comment: Where can I download QGIS 2.99? The last version in the website is 2.18.15?

Comment: You need to download the OSGeo4W network installer from here (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) and then install the development version of QGIS.

Comment: From the qgis website "For users that cannot use OSGeo4W for some reason or just prefer it there is also a weekly snapshot of qgis-dev from OSGeo4W as standalone installer (taken on monday). In the feature freeze phase that also acts as release candidate."   The download link is : https://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/?C=M;O=D