# Color polygons in different colors using geotools

Tags: polygon, style, geotools, four-color-theorem

I need to color polygons in different colors, ensuring that polygons sharing boundaries do not have the same color (the well-known [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)).

Is there a way to do that using [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org)?

Comment: If you don't find anything for GeoTools there is an OpenJUMP plugin that colors JTS geometries with five colors https://sourceforge.net/projects/ojmapcoloring/files/. Perhaps having a look at that GPL licensed source code could help you.

Comment: you could look at the plugins mentioned in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89015/four-color-theorem-for-qgis-4-colour)

Comment: And have a look at this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267638/selecting-different-colors-for-touching-polygons-in-random-color-ramp-in-qgis/267640#267640

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Four color theorem for QGIS? (4 colour)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89015/four-color-theorem-for-qgis-4-colour)

Comment: Not duplicate because OP wants to use GeoTools, not QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an [implementation](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1760511) that will colour most (some?) simpler maps with 5 colours, it turns out 4 colours is a very hard algorithm to understand so I skipped that and went with the [simpler 5 colours](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/32927/0/page/2). I also only implemented *Rule 1* rather than the more complex *rule 2* so it can only handle maps where there are polygons with fewer than 5 neighbours. This is true for all the polygon sets I've tested on, but your mileage may vary.

[image]

[image]