# How to apply the Four Colour theorem on GeoJSON feature collection with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, color, choropleth, four-color-theorem

Imagine you have a GeoJSON feature collection of adjacent colored polygons presented in a Leaflet map; in the present case the parishes of the city of Lisbon

[image]

```js
fetch('https://geoapi.pt/municipio/lisboa/freguesias?json=1').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
  const geojsons = data.geojsons
  
  var map = L.map('map')

  const bbox = geojsons.municipio.bbox
  const corner1 = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0])
  const corner2 = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2])
  const bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2)
  map.fitBounds(bounds)
  
  L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map)

  // feature collection
  const parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: geojsons.freguesias
  }

  // need this for color pallete
  const numberOfParishes = parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection.features.length
  parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection.features.forEach((parish, index) => {
    parish.properties.index = index
  })

  L.geoJson(parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection, {
    style
  }).addTo(map)

  function style (feature) {
    return {
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'white',
      dashArray: '3',
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.index, numberOfParishes)
    }
  }

})

// get random color
function getColor (index, size) {
  const colors = {
    3: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada'],
    4: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072'],
    5: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3'],
    6: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462'],
    7: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69'],
    8: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5'],
    9: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9'],
    10: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'],
    11: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#ccebc5'],
    12: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#ccebc5', '#ffed6f']
  }

  if (size < 3) {
    return colors[3][index]
  } else if (size <= 12) {
    return colors[size][index]
  } else {
    return colors[12][index % 12]
  }
}
```

How would you apply the Four Colour theorem or any suitable algorithm to avoid adjacent polygons to have the same color?

Comment: There's a qgis plugin that will generate a new attribute that you can style on.

Comment: @IanTurton thank you, but I need to Leaflet/Javascript

Comment: Good luck with that then. This may help https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/298105/79

Comment: Search for graph coloring algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way to color choropleth map so that no two adjacent features have the same color is to use `topojson` library (see https://github.com/topojson/topojson) to convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON and then use `topojson.neighbors` method to find neighbors for each feature and use this info when coloring features.

One simple way of implementing this could be the following code (which can be embellished to use more colors, but this is just proof of concept):

```
const colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#ccebc5', '#ffed6f']

function style (feature) {
  return {
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    fillColor: colors[feature.properties.colorIndex]
  }
}  

var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);


fetch('https://geoapi.pt/municipio/lisboa/freguesias?json=1').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
  const geojsons = data.geojsons;

  const bbox = geojsons.municipio.bbox;
  const corner1 = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0]);
  const corner2 = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2]);
  const bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  
  const parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: geojsons.freguesias
  };

  var topoJSON = topojson.topology([parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection], 1e4);
  var neighbors = topojson.neighbors(topoJSON.objects[0].geometries);
  
  var featureColors = [];
  parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection.features.forEach((parish, index) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      var found = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < neighbors[index].length; j++) {
        if (featureColors[neighbors[index][j]] == i) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) break;
    }
    featureColors[index] = i;
    parish.properties.colorIndex = i;
  });

  L.geoJson(parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection, {
    style
  }).addTo(map);
})
```

This is then the result:

[image]

Comment: What a fantastic posting this is. Working code example for tricky problem. I salute you sir.

Comment: Hmm... as much as I appreciate this code, it doesn't implement the 4 color theorum.  If you reduce the number of colors to 4, it doesn't work. You have 13 colors, but logically, that might not be enough for certain topographies.

Comment: @xpusostomos Of course you are right, it's just practical solution to given practical problem.